# Checbox Selecionados List View

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

Tenho um `ListView` onde no final eu tenho um `CheckBox` referenciando meus dados. Preciso criar um botão que dispare um método que percorra os `Checkbox` selecionados e pegue o seu valor. Como fazer este método?

```
                    <asp:ListView ID="lstGerenciamentoFrmAnaliseEficacia"  runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder"  OnPagePropertiesChanged="lstGerenciamentoFrmAnaliseEficacia_PagePropertiesChanged" DataKeyNames="QO_CODIGO, QAO_CODIGO, AAO_CODIGO">

                            <LayoutTemplate>

                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" runat="server" id="tblGerenciamentoFrmAnaliseEficacia">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr class="title" runat="server">
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Ocorrência</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Setor Notificado</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Tipo</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Data Ocorrência</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Análise</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Ação</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Título</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Status</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Execução</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom">Responsável</th>
                                                <th runat="server" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom"></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="pgrGerenciamentoFrmAnalises" PagedControlID="lstGerenciamentoFrmAnalises">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                                <PagerTemplate>
                                                    <p><strong><%# Container.TotalRowCount %></strong> registro(s) encontrado(s).</p>
                                                </PagerTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField
                                                ButtonCssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                                ShowFirstPageButton="true"
                                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
                                                ShowNextPageButton="false"
                                                ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                                FirstPageText="Primeira" />
                                            <asp:NumericPagerField
                                                NumericButtonCssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                                NextPreviousButtonCssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                                CurrentPageLabelCssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" />
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField
                                                ButtonCssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                                ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
                                                ShowNextPageButton="false"
                                                ShowLastPageButton="true"
                                                LastPageText="Última" />
                                        </Fields>
                                    </asp:DataPager>
                                </div>

                            </LayoutTemplate>


                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Nenhum registro foi encontrado.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>

                            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                                <td />
                            </EmptyItemTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("QO_CODIGO") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-3 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("ST_DESCRICAO") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("QTO_DESCRICAO") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("QO_DATAREGISTRO")) ? "N/A" : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("QO_DATAREGISTRO")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("QAO_CODIGO") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("AAO_CODIGO") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("AAO_TITULO") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("AAO_STATUS").Equals("P") ? "Prevista" : Eval("AAO_STATUS").Equals("C") ? "Concluída" : Eval("AAO_STATUS").Equals("E") ? "Eficaz" : Eval("AAO_STATUS").Equals("I") ? "Ineficaz" : string.Empty %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("AAO_DATAEXECUCAO")) ? "N/A" : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("AAO_DATAEXECUCAO")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("USU_NOME") %></td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle"><asp:CheckBox value='<%# Eval("QO_CODIGO") + "," + Eval("QAO_CODIGO")  + "," + Eval("AAO_CODIGO")%>' runat="server" id="chkFrmAnaliseEficacia" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi sua pergunta, existem várias formas de fazer isto, uma das formas é percorrer a listView, verificando se possui checkbox ativado, e pegar seu valor, segue um código de exemplo:

```
//Evento do Botão
protected void btValores_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  foreach( ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items )
  {
    var check = item.FindControl("chkFrmAnaliseEficacia") as CheckBox;
    if(check != null && check.Checked )
    {
      string value = check.Value;
    }
  }
}
```